# How to Remove Activation Context Generation Failed - Dependent Assembly - Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

I am very new to Windows-based development - in fact this is my first project.

I have a Windows-based project that was compiled into a dll file using Visual Studio 2008.
I want to remove the dependency on VS2008 and have it compiled through the Makefile build-system that we have at work.
The compilation works.

However when I run the resultant dll (I mean run the test app that loads the resultant dll), I get an error - "The Application was unable to start correctly - 0xc0150002)"
I checked the Event logs - and I see the message mentioned in this post's title.

Googling said that - 
1) I should restart the machine - did not work
2) Install VS2008 on the machine on which I am running the dll - Not really a feasible option
3) The app that loads the dll (which is just a test app) also gets compiled via the VS2008 - should also be compiled through the build system.

I have checked that everything is 32-bit.

So my question is - is there a flag that I am missing to handle this Dependent Assembly error?
The reason I ask is - the previous dll (one built through VS2008) can be run without any issue - and hence I think I might be missing some flag/compilation option.

Sorry for the vague newbie question. I would even appreciate if someone could point me to sources to read to get more details about this.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to deploy the Release build of your DLL to another machine, you cannot get the debug version of the CRT installed.

Comment: Various sources on the internet say it is possible to run a debug build using private assemblies (within your organization, no redistribution to third parties) however it does not appear to be possible, due to a series of severe technologically braindead decisions by Microsoft, bless their pointy heads.

Answer (score 1):

Could the VS2008 solution be set to "debug" mode instead of "release" mode, so when you built the DLL, you got the debug version, hence asking for debug dependancies.
Try setting the solution in VS2008 to build a release version and see if that DLL gives the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue with a vendor-supplied set of DLL's, and this fixed it for me.